# Application configuration file

Tags: android

I need a place where I can store basic application configuration(URIs, DB-name, external storage folder-names, etc) in XML or any other decent format.

Is it /assets folder ? If so - give a basic example of using it in conjunction with XML files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is: Resources folder: res/values/strings.

There you can place all the strings you want. 
To use locale specific strings create multiple value folders ending with the locale suffix. 
values folder (default):

```
<string name="app_name">My android app name</string>
<string name="email">myemail@gmail.com</string>
<string name="contact_me">Contact me</string>
```

values-PT folder (portuguese strings):

```
<string name="app_name">My android app name in PT</string>
<string name="email">myemail@gmail.com</string>
<string name="contact_me">pt string for contact me</string>
```

then just use them as: `yourPackage.R.string.email` on your classes.

Comment: Does it mean I'll need to copy those in each locale that I would decide to provide user with ?

Comment: No, on the res folder just create multiple value folders for each locale. values (will be the default one), values-ES, values-PT... Then inside each one put the same strings with the locale values.

Comment: You've made just what I supposed - copied those strings to another file whereas in my opinion configuration(URI links, etc) is locale independent and I don't want to copy it in each locale file I would have to create.

Comment: If you don't paste those strings on the specific string files, the app will use the defualt ones. Therefor you won't have a problem with that and it'll be locale independent :)